# Integrate existing web application(.NET) to CMS like Ubranco or DotNetNuke

Tags: .net, content-management-system

I have a web application that I want to extend by integrating a CMS. I had a look online and everyone seems to suggest Dotnetnuke and Ubranco.

What I don't understand is

It is possible to integrate these CMS to an existing website?

Do I have to install anything on the server?(I can't it is a shared hosting)
Could you suggest an alternative?

Thanks

Comment: Typically, you would integrate application features into a CMS, not integrate the CMS into ab existing application.

Answer (score 0):

Most CMS systems store contents in a database.You can store the description and link to the application in data base.But you should store the application in a specific folder so that the links will refer to the default page of your apps